# get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Tags: nginx

I have already written "TRUSTED CERTIFICATE" and "END TRUSTED CERTIFICATE" in my text file but an error occurred.

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/ssl/certs/surveyspan.crt") failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to [so]. Please take some time to review the [tour] and [ask]?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/563555/484449

Comment: The PEM marker lines are **5 dashes**, BEGIN/END type, **5 dashes**. However, the data _between_ those lines must be in a specific and complicated format; if you don't already have a PEM file you won't be able to create valid data, and if you do already have a PEM file it already has the BEGIN/END lines and doesn't need any editing. Moreover in spite of the error text OpenSSL and thus nginx can read _either_ a cert in 'trusted' _format or_ a plain cert without trust info (but actually trusted), which is much more common. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: 2019/11/13 12:03:27 [emerg] 22398#22398: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/ssl/private/surveyspan.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed                          
FACING THIS ISSUE NOW..

Comment: I have addded this in nginx.conf                                                                   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/surveyspan_com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/surveyspan.key; but when i test nginx -t showing error :                                                                                             
 nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate_key" is defined for certificate "/etc/ssl/certs/surveyspan_com.crt"   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed